# Symfony is caching user information in my navbar, so it is sharred between users

Tags: symfony, caching

I'm using the native cache system on my project.
I have the following code in my navbar :

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
              <a href="{{ path('buildy_bundle_search') }}">Recherche</a>
        </li>
        {% if is_granted("ROLE_USER") %}
            <li>
               <a href="{{ path('buildy_bundle_search_for_add') }}">Ajouter</a>
           </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
```

But if I open my site in 2 différents browsers and I loggeg in on one browser, I can see these links on the other browser as well.

It seems to be due to the cache bcause I have to files in my PHP sessions folder (one for each browser).

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What kind of caches do you use in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Using edge side includes (ESI) you can specify different caching requirements for specific elements of a page, rather than the page as a whole. See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#using-edge-side-includes

My config.yml:

```
session: 
    lifetime: 3600
    save_path: %kernel.root_dir%/var/sessions
esi: { enabled: true }
```

My twig file:

```
<div class="header-left">
    {% render 'MyUserBundle:Account:menu' with {}, {'standalone': true} %}
</div>
```

This works in Symfony 2.1, but there will probably be subtle changes in later versions.

Comment: yes but I don't think this is the solution. I acn't see if it's a caching problem or a session issue. I tried to install memcached for the sessions, the result is the same. What makes me feel it's not a cache issue is that the debugbar of symfony sees the session informations

Comment: You will see this behaviour in the default setup - I witnessed the exact same thing when starting to build my app (I'm also using FOSUserBundle). Using ESI resolved the problem for me.

Comment: thank you but I think it is not a caching problem because I can see the session in my debug bar (on both browsers), dans there is no cache on the debbug bar : its's written "Loggeg in as my_username" "authenticated yes"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm not sur it's a caching issue.
If I open my dev app in two browsers, in the debug bar, I can see that my session is shared...

I'm using the FOSuserBundle to manage users and authentication.
Here is my config.yml :

```
session:
    # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/sessions'
```

And here my security.yml :
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username


firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4

        logout:
            target: /
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/add, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/vote, role: ROLE_USER }
```

I really don't understand what's going on...

Comment: What happens if you remove (comment out) the handler_id from your config.yml?

Comment: Hello,I have finally found

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution.
It was something due to my app.php and app_dev.php files.
I tried some config 1 day, and I had forgotten......
Here is what I had in my code :

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

AppCache was the problem.

Thanks for your help guys !